# how to set toolbar on FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-toolbar

I want to set **toolbar** on my activity which extends **FragmentActivity**. I know that for use `setSuppoertActionBar(toolbar)` method we extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` but I override the `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)` method which is final in `AppCompatActivity` and final method cannot override. so I'm restricted to extends `FragmentActivity`.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);   -> error is here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
       // Inflate the menu
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_search:
                onSearchRequested();
                break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

I saw many answers related to that question but everyone says extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` but I want to set toolbar as well as override `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)` method.

what should I do, please help.

Comment: Have tried `onOptionsItemSelected` yet?

Comment: yeah I got it, I found my solution by your suggestion. I extends AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity and changed the onMenuItemSelected() method with onOptionsItemSelected() method. thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This thing is good when you are using `NavigationDrawer`**
**use this**:-

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**then set Toolbar Title according to different fragment with different Titles in `onNavigationItemSelected`** :-

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        sfm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_id) {
            fragment = new YourFragment();
            toolbar.setTitle("SET TOOLBAR NAME");
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_id2) {
            fragment = new YourFragment();
            toolbar.setTitle("SET TOOLBAR NAME");
        }
```

**For single fragment, first customize your `style.xml` like this :-**

```
<style name="YourStyleName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
// ToDo as you want to do or as per your requirement

</style>
```

**then apply into your custom `toolbar`:-**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/YourStyleName" >

  // ...........


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own `toolbar`:

First set up the main theme to extend `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="style_1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Remember to apply the theme:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setTheme(R.style.style_1);
    // ...
}
```

then in your `Activity`'s xml you can set your own custom `toolbar`:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>
```

where `@layout/my_toolbar` may look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

    <!-- insert your views here -->
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First set style as  
<style name="style_1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
then

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Home");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your Activity from AppCompatActivity as this includes support for Fragments and the Toolbar.
And then override the

> onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() methods

You shouldn't be overriding

> onMenuItemSelected()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { ...

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ....


    ....
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      ...
         ...
    }


   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   ...
  }
```